# флаг [B] mod_rewrite

Tags: apache

Есть проблема с пониманием флага [B] в RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule "^search/(.*)$" "/file.php?term=$1" [B]
```

Если я понял правильно, то если введу запрос: search/a & b, то символ & должен был экранироваться перед трансформацией. Но этого не произошло: "a%20&%20b". Что я понял не так?

Comment: это вы в `print_r($_GET['term'])` вывод посмотрели?

Comment: нет, в строке запроса

Comment: и как директивы апача вообще связаны со строкой запроса по вашему?